# Return columns for top k values based on two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

The data is as follows: df1 consist of users and their corresponding probabilities for A to D (these values are already given/computed; df2 consist of the relationship between the same users, for instance, user 1001 is closer to user 1004 and 1003 as shown in the first row of df2. Here are the dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "user1":[1001,1002,1003,1004],
        "A" :[0.003, 0.1, 0.13, 0.23],
        "B" :[0.03, 0.3, 0.22, 0.43],
        "C" :[0.5, 0.1, 0.08, 0.04],
        "D" :[0.453,0.2,0.2,0.14]
})
df1.set_index("user1", inplace=True)


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "user2":[1001, 1002],
    "top1":["1004","1003"],
    "top2":["1003", "1002"]
})
```

If we print the two dataframes, we get the following:

```
print(df1)
print(df2)


        A     B     C      D
user1                          
1001   0.003  0.03  0.50  0.453
1002   0.100  0.30  0.10  0.200
1003   0.130  0.22  0.08  0.200
1004   0.230  0.43  0.04  0.140


   user2     top1     top2
0   1001     1004     1003
1   1002     1003     1002
```

**What I am trying to do is to produce the following output:**

```
user     1     2      3        4
1001     B     A      B        D
1002     B     D      B        D
```

The output simply says if I look at first row in df2, I take top1 and top2 users for user 1001 in that row and find the corresponding top two probability values in df2 and return their column. Thus, for user1001 is close to 1004 and 1003. So I look in df1, top 2 probabilities values for 1004 are 0.43 and 0.23 in B and A respectively, 1003 has top values in B and D, and that's how I get the first row in the output.

I have tried the following code but to no avail.

```
  df1 = df1.T


 df3 = pd.DataFrame({row["user2"]:np.append(df1[row["top1"]].nlargest(2).index.values,
                                              df1[row["top2"]].nlargest(2).index.values)
                      for (i, row) in df2.iterrows()}).T
```

Comment: For top1 and top2, your user ids are string in df2 but int in df1. Is it possible to have a single type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an intermediate dataframe `df1_prefs` to simplify your task.

```
df1_prefs = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        user: df1.loc[user].sort_values(ascending=False).index 
        for user in df1.index
    }
).T[[0, 1]]
```

You get this dataframe :

```
      0  1
1001  C  D
1002  B  D
1003  B  D
1004  B  A
```

Then, you can merge the rows of your targets index :

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    df2.loc[i]['user2']: 
    df1_prefs.loc[int(df2.loc[i]['top1'])].append(df1_prefs.loc[int(df2.loc[i]['top2'])], ignore_index=True)
    for i in df2.index
}).T
```

Output:

```
      0  1  2  3
1001  B  A  B  D
1002  B  D  B  D
```

There are probably ways to make it simpler, but the idea works.

Also, be careful that your indexes do not always have the same type. In one case it is an int, in the other a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a dataframe with the top2 per user, then `merge`:

```
df3 = (df1.stack()
          .groupby(level=0).nlargest(2)
          .reset_index(level=[1,2])
          .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby(level='user1').cumcount()+1)
          .pivot(index='user1', columns='col', values='level_2')
      )

(df2.merge(df3, left_on='top1', right_index=True)
    .merge(df3.set_axis([3,4], axis=1), left_on='top2', right_index=True)
    .filter(regex='^(?!top)')
)
```

output:

```
   user2  1  2  3  4
0   1001  B  A  B  D
1   1002  B  D  B  D
```

Comment: I am getting an error with this method, says `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
` and I am not sure if its a problem on my end.

Comment: convert df2 to an integer: ``df2.astype(int)`` before proceeding

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks for the suggestion, I have converted df2 to integer and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: that was the erorr I encountered when attempting a solution; have a look at the dtypes for each dataframe; one of them is an object; once you identify the culprit, do the astype thing, and dont forget to assign back to the df: ``df2 = df2.astype(int)``

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a very concise way - but here is something that works -

```
#We define a function that we can apply to each row of `df2`
def get_top_2(row):
    _from_top_1_column = sorted(df1.loc[int(row['top1']), :].to_dict().items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    top_2_col_names_from_top_1_column = [colname for colname, value in _from_top_1_column][:2]
    _from_top_2_column = sorted(df1.loc[int(row['top2']), :].to_dict().items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    top_2_col_names_from_top_2_column = [colname for colname, value in _from_top_2_column][:2]
    top_4 = top_2_col_names_from_top_1_column + top_2_col_names_from_top_2_column
    return '|'.join(top_4)

df2.apply(get_top_2, axis=1).str.split('|', expand=True)
   0  1  2  3
0  B  A  B  D
1  B  D  B  D
```

The convoluted part within that function is probably -

```
 _from_top_1_column = sorted(df1.loc[int(row['top1']), :].to_dict().items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

What it is doing is -

1. Pick the row corresponding to the 'top1' column from `df1`
2. Convert it to a `dict` (and then get the `dict().items()`) so that you
   get the row entries as `(columnname,  value)`
3. Sort this list of tuples by the value - descending

Comment: I have 100K columns in df1,  and for simplicity I have converted them to `int` values instead of `A,B, C....`  When I run this code I am getting an error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`. Where do you suggest I can change to solve this error?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you are getting this error - but my guess is in the `return '|'.join(top_4)` statement. If that is the case - then you can change it to `return '|'.join(map(str, top_4))`

Comment: If that is not where the error is, please edit your question to include the additional information.

Comment: that worked, additional information on time: It took `8216.302s ` to run given `[50618 rows x 6236 columns]` on a Mac 16G.